# Calculate percentage sql table

Tags: sql, ms-access, percentage

I have a table called Fruits with records like Apples, Oranges, etc

How do I write a query that tells me the percentage of Apples?

What I have tried till now:

```
select 

sum(case when APPLES = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(APPLES)

from FRUITS;
```

Comment: We are here to help you to find a solution to a problem, we're not here to do your homework... what did you try till now?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: A simple MS Access database

Comment: It looks to me like you're using SQL Server syntax in an MS Access database. If it's an `.mdb` and not an `.adp` or `.accdp` file, that syntax will not work.

Comment: Now that you've updated the question, please confirm: You have a column for each different fruit, which can be 'Yes' or 'No'. Only one of these can be 'Yes' in each row, and each row represents a single fruit. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm assuming when you say "a simple MS Access database" that you mean an `.mdb` and not an `.adp` or `.accdp` file.

Second, you're experiencing pain because your table is not normalized properly. You have data as column names! If you want to add another fruit, you'll have to add a new column--that's not good design (sorry to say this, but it's true).

So far, your query can look something like this (there is no need to do a join or scan the table twice).

```
SELECT
   Sum(Iif(Apple = "yes", 1, 0)) * 100 / Count(*)
FROM
   Fruits
;
```

If you had your column designed so data was in rows instead of column names, the query would look more like this:

```
SELECT
   Sum(Iif(Fruit = "apple", 1, 0)) * 100 / Count(*)
FROM
   Fruits
;
```

Until I understand the structure of your data better, I can't make any more recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Inner join query getting a total no of fruits and outer query is group by fruit and count total number of fruits available by fruits:

```
select fruit, (count(*)/A.total_count) as perc_fruit from
table 
inner join (
 select count(*) as total_count from table 
) as A 
group by fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

If a table contains two columns furit_name and no_of_fruits, try executing below query.

**SELECT** (100 * (
  (SELECT NO_OF_FRUITS FROM fruits WHERE fruit_name='APPLE'
  ) /
  (SELECT SUM(NO_OF_FRUITS) FROM fruits
  ) )) **AS Percentage_FRUITS**
**FROM dual**;

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

EDIT:

[image: Table]

```
select 
Sum(IIF(Apple,1,0) * 100) / count(*) 
from FRUITS;

-- Where `Apple` is of Datatype (Yes/No)
```

Demo:

[image: Result]

Comment: I didn't downvote, but for one thing it's MS Access (which I know you didn't know at the time) and for another you're scanning the table twice.